# How to manage datasets in MLflow?

Tags: python, machine-learning, dataset, mlflow

Consider the following code snippet taken from MLflow [documentation page](https://mlflow.org/docs/latest/python_api/mlflow.data.html#mlflow-data):

```py
import mlflow.data
import pandas as pd
from mlflow.data.pandas_dataset import PandasDataset

# Construct a Pandas DataFrame using iris flower data from a web URL
dataset_source_url = "http://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/wine-quality/winequality-red.csv"
df = pd.read_csv(dataset_source_url)
# Construct an MLflow PandasDataset from the Pandas DataFrame, and specify the web URL
# as the source
dataset: PandasDataset = mlflow.data.from_pandas(df, source=dataset_source_url)

with mlflow.start_run():
    # Log the dataset to the MLflow Run. Specify the "training" context to indicate that the
    # dataset is used for model training
    mlflow.log_input(dataset, context="training")

# Retrieve the run, including dataset information
run = mlflow.get_run(mlflow.last_active_run().info.run_id)
dataset_info = run.inputs.dataset_inputs[0].dataset
print(f"Dataset name: {dataset_info.name}")
print(f"Dataset digest: {dataset_info.digest}")
print(f"Dataset profile: {dataset_info.profile}")
print(f"Dataset schema: {dataset_info.schema}")

# Load the dataset's source, which downloads the content from the source URL to the local
# filesystem
dataset_source = mlflow.data.get_source(dataset_info)
dataset_source.load()
```

This code is starting a new run and logging an input which is a dataset. Does this mean that in MLflow we are saving datasets as separate runs? If that's the case, how are we associating the training of a model that has its own run to a dataset? I'm confused how MLflow handles/tracks datasets! TBH, I was expecting datasets to be a different entity type (than runs) and we could link them to each run which is for a model training.